# Why does a shared spreadsheet doesn´t work properly after having authorized it?

Tags: google-apps-script, share, spreadsheet

I´ve created a spreadsheet with a script in it. I shared it with the url /copy and copied it to another account i own, just to test it. Then when i run the script it asks me authorizations. I approve them, the script runs and finish, but there are some sentences that don´t run beyond having authorized them. Some of those sentences are:

```
GmailApp.markMessageRead(mail[0]);   
GmailApp.moveMessageToTrash(mail[0]);
sheet[2].sort(2);
sheet[2].sort(1);
sheet[2].deleteColumn(3);
```

The difference i see is that when i run the script for the first time in the original account pops up the "this app is not verify" window (i accept the request), but in the other account this pop up doesn´t show. Only the next authorization pops up.

The script takes an attachment from an email copies it in drive, converts it to spreadsheet and takes the glucose values for ordering them in the main sheet.

I can´t really find the solution and i´d like to share this spreadsheet because it could be useful for many diabetics. It works properly for me, but not when i share it.

This is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ozIhv6DWD5O9uzn9z713HT1N0cFfncgwgKZ9FYxY0HQ/copy

I´m new at GAS and this is my first script. I´m a C programmer.
Thank you!

I paste the code below.

```
function myTidySgr() {
  var sps = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = sps.getSheets();
  var rowsprincipal = sheet[0].getDataRange();
  var principal = rowsprincipal.getValues();
  var busqueda = GmailApp.search("is:unread subject:(exportar.csv) 
  has:attachment", 0, 100);
  var mail = busqueda[0].getMessages();
  var MySgr = mail[0].getAttachments(); 
  var blob = MySgr[0].copyBlob();       
  GmailApp.markMessageRead(mail[0]);   
  }
```

Comment: hi Julio! thanks for your question. could you edit it and add some tags specifying what language(s) and other technologies you're using? it's not really clear from the post, try and imagine that you're asking someone who has no context at all for what you're doing and provide a little more detail!

Comment: Hello. Is that ok? I dont know what else to explain. I could copy the whole code if necessary...

Comment: Hi there @Julio! Yes, copy the code please. That way we can take a look to help.

Comment: Provide [mcve] instead of all code.

Comment: Script editor> view> executions. Any error?

Comment: No errors in executions.

Answer (score 0):

i found out what the problem is!
When i share the spreadsheet to a G Suite account it doesn´t work because i cannot authorize some permissions because i´m not the G Suite´s administrator. Apparently there are some security limitations.
I copied the spreadsheet to a common gmail account and it worked properly.
Thanks anyway!
Regards